# Add reporting Services After SQL Installed (update ?)

Tags: sql, reporting-services, windows-clustering

I installed à cluster of SQL Server 2016. After installing SP1 and cumulative update 8, I would like to add reporting service.

Question : do I have to reinstall each update after installing reporting service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, just add Reporting Services feature to the SQL installation.

Comment: Thanks for answer !